# Store Geolocation coordinates in Grails Domain models?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I want to store the geolocation coordinates longitude and latitude such that I later can specify an area and query like this in GORM:

```
SELECT * FROM Place 
WHERE lat BETWEEN :x1 AND :x2
AND lng BETWEEN :y1 AND :y2
```

How do I have to store the coordinates in my Domain? My underlying database is MySQL.

What I propose is:

```
class Place {
  double lat
  double lng
}
```

I also read that there is a spacial index. Would you recommend using this with Grails? If so how do I map my domain to fit this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like the Hibernate spatial plugin: https://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-spatial

Comment: `Last Updated: 30 September 2011` hmmm

Comment: I also find this plugin but it is outdated. Is no one else using mysql spatial index and Grails together?

Comment: Is spatial extension included in mysql 5.5? I did not find any way to make an installation.

Answer (score 0):

Spatial index or geo-search has nothing to do with GORM itself, it's a feature of databases like Postgres or Mongo. So, if you want to use it, you must go for low-level or plugin-specific querying.

If you want store and query the coord-pairs as you have shown, then it's fine. You can tweak the columns by setting the max float precision to 6 (corresponds to 10 meter accuracy) and set the index on them